# Check button text in jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following react-native test code.

```
it('should render a <BorderlessButton />', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(BorderlessButton)).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(BorderlessButton).props.text.toEqual('D'));
  });
```

This doesn't work properly. What I want to do is to check the button text. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

I think we need to replace `.props` with `.props()`, also the syntax for `toEqual` should be like this -:

```
expect(wrapper.find(BorderlessButton).props().text).toEqual('D');
```

Comment: @Shashika Please accept and upvote the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked with the following syntax

```
expect(wrapper.find(BorderlessButton).text()).toEqual('D');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
describe("Test Button component", () => {
  let container = null;
  let clickFn = null;
  beforeEach(() => {
    clickFn = jest.fn();
    container = shallow(<Button buttonAction={clickFn} value="send" />);
  });
  it("button value", () => {
    
    expect(container.find("button").props().value).toEqual("send");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Jest Quickstart](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/#quickstart) documentation:

```
test('loads and displays greeting', async () => {
  render(<Fetch url="/greeting" />)

  expect(screen.getByRole('heading')).toHaveTextContent('hello there')
  expect(screen.getByRole('button')).toBeDisabled()
})
```

It looks like the ***toHaveTextContent*** method should work for you.
Personally, I don't use getByRole on projects, but usually getByTestId.
It looks like this:

```
expect(screen.getByTestId('button-test-id')).toHaveTextContent('value')
```

Comment: FWIW, favoring `getByTestId` over `getByRole` and other query types is discouraged by the authors of Testing-Library: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid.